# Customize dropdown dialog items in WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-theme

I am including a WebView into an Android View. In the page loaded in the WebView I have a drop down. When I click on the drop down, a dialog appears (it is the native Android dialog) but it has a bad look.

I would like to change those styles.

It seems to me that I need to change a theme style in the xml but I don't know which property could affect the webView dialog.

```
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.App</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.App</item>

<style name="DropDownListView.App" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/abs__list_divider_holo_light</item>

</style>
```

I have tried to change this property but nothing happened.
What property should I change to modify dialog list style?

Thanks

Comment: What is "a bad look"?

Comment: List item separator, text size and selected item background

Comment: Post a screenshot of what you have vs. what you want. Alternatively, delete the question if it's no longer relevant.